# Use of virtual property in model class in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DesignationID { get; set; }

    **public virtual Designation Designation { get; set; }**
}
```

**Context Class**

```
public class DataClass : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Designation> Designation { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModelClass**

```
public class Class3
{
    public Employee Employee{ get; set; }
    public Designation Designation { get; set; }
}
```

**Query:-**

```
(from emp in dc.Employee
    join designation in dc.Designation 
        on emp.DesignationID equals  designation.DesignationID 

    select new Class3
     {
        Employee = emp ,
        Designation = designation,
     }).Single();
```

If you look into the employee class property

```
public virtual Designation Designation { get; set; }
```

This property is of no use even when I delete this property, code works

Is my approach is right ?? because every example on internet defines this property  but in my case it is of no use, I think these are for projection purposes but do not understand the mechanism of it

Thanks

Comment: `Virtual` is used to implement a property/variable, while at the same time allows for it to be overridden by its subclasses. If there is no override, it ensures that there's some implementation. Hope that helps. [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to query data using self-made joins as you've shown in your example, you can safely delete `Employee.Designation` property.

Usually virtual properties are being used by Entity Framework for the [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy) of related objects (process whereby an entity or collection of entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed).

So using lazy loading your query can be written as

```
(from emp in dc.Employee
    select new Class3
     {
        Employee = emp ,
        Designation = emp.Designation,
     }).Single();
```

and EntityFramework will make join by itself.

Side note: in this case it looks like your `Class3` viewmodel almost duplicates `Employee` model so it looks redundant. But I suppose it could be some syntetic example, not real one.

Comment: Thank you Andy Korneyev, It looks so easy to query with virtual properties

Comment: Hey Andy stuck with a little problem here

(from emp in dc.Employee
    select new Employee
     {
        Employee = emp ,
        Designation = emp.Designation,
     }).Single();

Its giving me error "Models.Employee does not contain a definition for Employee"

On the line Employee = emp,

Comment: @FahadMeraj It looks like you're trying to get rid of `Class3` you've previously used as viewmodel and change your viewmodel type to `Employee`. In this case your query should be just `from emp in dc.Employee select  emp` since `emp` is already of type `Employee` and there is no need to wrap it again. But note, you're using `single()` linq retrieving method and there is no `where` condition in your query. In this case, if query returns more than one value, exception will be thrown. Probably you've just omitted `where` condition.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual properties are mainly used by the Entity Framework and are not used in your application (as far as i can see). So you can delete it safely :).

What they actually do:
On runtime a new class will be created for your virtual property and that one will be used by the Entity Framework because it is faster then using the regular class.

**Edit**
It is called [lazy loading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Teun Vos, I understood now

Answer (score 2):

Virtual properties in models are often created/used by ORMs (eg Entity Framework / nHibernate) for lazy loading (they only load the data when they are accessed).

If this was the case here, I would expect to see *all* of your properties with Virtual applied, which they're not.

In this case, it doesn't appear to need to be virtual and it's not clear if the question is related to the property being virtual or about the existence of the property at all.

As you're not using the `Desgination` property, you can safely remove it - disclaimer: if you app breaks from removing it, put it back quick.... :)

If the class was created automatically, then it's likely you have a relationship in your database.

With the property there, you can do away with your `class3` completely by setting `emp.Desgination`.

Comment: Thank you freedomn-m, I understood now